# Password reset link gets redirected to swagger

Tags: abp

When clicking on the password reset link sended by Forgot-Password-Email, it gets redirected to the swagger api page instead of the app password reset page of angular account module. I'm using ABP version 4.**4**.2.

Log:

```
[INF] Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://MyServer:MyApiPort/?userId=b7f3736f-08c2-bf57-a515-39fb28b41c19&__tenant=&resetToken=CfDJ8IxpuMPgrKNKjI1u2e2ZAtOOLUHe6OX2Ij5%2BH68fAkOeFPafRMUZ3I9OF%2Biqr3FoBEteth2P5NC6GQDWPjoI%2BZRv%2BjATH0b8vm2UC%2FIHrp%2B%2BIdER9tGBDySInA631AGxaO3HATlpBHdXsNSkfIenqHllxzEe4WeJlyqjem%2BJ8WcBC1c%2FYlxR7xxHDJDiyUyhkRy%2Bx6PMKddc5w2APu5p1f3JAfCzdbTBYJF4REQYAPCd - -
[INF] Executing endpoint 'MyAPP.Controllers.HomeController.Index (MyAPP.HttpApi.Host)'
[INF] Route matched with {action = "Index", controller = "Home", area = "", page = ""}. Executing controller action with signature Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ActionResult Index() on controller MyAPP.Controllers.HomeController (MyAPP.HttpApi.Host).
[INF] Executing RedirectResult, redirecting to /swagger.
```

appsetting:

```
"App": {
    "SelfUrl": "http://MyServer:MyApiPort",
    "CorsOrigins": "http://MyServer:MyAppPort",
    "RedirectAllowedUrls": "http://MyServer:MyAppPort"
  },
```

Is there something else to configure to get redirecting correctly?

Many thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

First of all, thank you very much for the information you provided.
I have done research on the subject and I think that this is due to the absence of `returnUrl` in the log record you provided.

> [INF] Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://MyServer:MyApiPort/?userId=b7f3736f-08c2-bf57-a515-39fb28b41c19&__tenant=&resetToken=CfDJ8IxpuMPgrKNKjI1u2e2ZAtOOLUHe6OX2Ij5%2BH68fAkOeFPafRMUZ3I9OF%2Biqr3FoBEteth2P5NC6GQDWPjoI%2BZRv%2BjATH0b8vm2UC%2FIHrp%2B%2BIdER9tGBDySInA631AGxaO3HATlpBHdXsNSkfIenqHllxzEe4WeJlyqjem%2BJ8WcBC1c%2FYlxR7xxHDJDiyUyhkRy%2Bx6PMKddc5w2APu5p1f3JAfCzdbTBYJF4REQYAPCd - -

This is of course a very superficial explanation, so, I have a few questions to understand the problem more clearly:

1. Do you have the same problem when you run it locally?
2. All your steps. For example, here are the steps I use to better understand this situation.

**My Steps:**

1. Project download with `abp new Angular.SeperteadMongiLish -t app -u angular --mobile none --separate-identity-server --database-provider mongodb -csf --version 4.4.2` command
2. I did the necessary steps to run the application
3. I clicked login in Angular UI.
4. I checked the URL here:

```
https://localhost:44356/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2Fconnect%2Fauthorize%2Fcallback%3Fresponse_type%3Dcode%26client_id%3DSeperteadMongiLish_App%26state%3DRHNCSDFjanZHbHlJTmRRdWtMeG9qZktQODRNek5NOXpUTHN4TmZQUUJkTThz%26redirect_uri%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A4200%26scope%3Doffline_access%2520openid%2520profile%2520role%2520email%2520phone%2520SeperteadMongiLish%26code_challenge%3D3P4R2O-GJcOHPNBAySMMwYMKp9jeevEWT3SR-1x2FTA%26code_challenge_method%3DS256%26nonce%3DRHNCSDFjanZHbHlJTmRRdWtMeG9qZktQODRNek5NOXpUTHN4TmZQUUJkTThz%26culture%3Den%26ui-culture%3Den
```

5. On the login screen that opens, I clicked the `Forgot Password?` button.
6. etc.

Comment: Thank you for looking into it. I tried it on local and the link does not have the `returnURL` part neither. My App didnt start with 4.4.2 actually, it's been developed since earlier version 3.* and then 4.2. and the 4.4 i think, but back then password reset was not activated, until now with 4.4.2. So maybe this is the problem. I will try it in a new project. and here is the link on local: http://localhost:44318/?userId=b7f3736f-08c2-bf57-a515-39fb28b41c19&__tenant=&resetToken=CfDJ8Bd71ahER41HsTRsP6tinr0gPAWCi51fdj2UhNGL7Bcfie%2FyQPDeWJNSlfmvo1wvNdSoiwiXqURaL1rZ0L6PosNxEBpAMhN%2FK4c6......

Comment: Please let me know if this problem persists in the project you created in `ABP 4.*.*` version :)

Comment: In a new project it's working fine. Compare to the new project, there are two lines of code in `ConfigureUrls` missing: `options.Applications["Angular"].RootUrl = configuration["App:ClientUrl"]; options.Applications["Angular"].Urls[AccountUrlNames.PasswordReset] = "account/reset-password";`  I installed the augular account module manuelly as it cames out earlier this year, maybe this part of code was not yet included in the install package back then. Thanks again for your tip. :)

Comment: hi @berkansasmaz I got one more question about this. Everything works perfectly on localhost, was also actually able to reset the password. After deployed on IIS, the reset link keeps getting 404. this is the link that works: `http://localhost:4200/account/reset-password?userId=b7f3736f-08c2-bf57-a515-39fb28b41c19&__tenant=&resetToken=CfDJ8Bd71....` and this is that gets 404: `http://MyServer:4200/account/reset-password?userId=b7f3736f-08c2-bf57-a515-39fb28b41c19&__tenant=&resetToken=CfDJ8OObj....` do you have any advise on this?

Comment: It looks like your `clientUrl` is missing from your `appsettings.json` file, it might be related to it. If it is not related to that, it would be great if you could specify the relevant log record and whether the problem occurred while logging in.

Comment: `clientUrl` is there, and no problem whlie logging in or change password after login. this 404 occurrs only when i click on the password reset link and there is nothing in the backend log, it seems angular doesnt render this page: `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)`, but it's working fine locally. so i am now confused.

Comment: I'm just commenting, maybe you haven't configured your email settings. To test this, you can click the email verify button in the `Profile info` section of the `/account/manage` section. If it gives an error there, you need to enter the email server settings.

Comment: Thanks, but don't think this is about the email settings, because I have already received the mail for password reset. it's the link in that email that gets 404 after deploying on IIS.